# Mule ESB catch plain text message and transform it to SOAP

Tags: soap, esb, plaintext, mule-component

I'm doing some testing with Mule ESB. I want to receive come plain text over TCP and convert it to a soap Message, for that I created a TCP connector a logger and an echo Component

[image: Muleflow]

I'm sending a simple "Hello" and getting the following error con mule console

> ERROR 2016-01-27 09:10:54,402 [[mule].connector.tcp.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: An error occurred while verifying your connection.  You may not be using a consistent protocol on your TCP transport. Please read the documentation for the TCP transport, paying particular attention to the protocol parameter.

I have been playing with the Transformer and Metadata parameter but still could´t make it work. How do I config the connector so It knows how to dial with the Text input?

Comment: Thanks Dijkgraaf for the editing.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same problem:
I solve this by adding the "tcp:direct-protocol payloadOnly=true protocol" in TCP connector->general->connector configuration->protocol.

After that I got no problems receiving neither text not data

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consume a WS from your HTTP request you could use the "Parte Template" Transformer and load the SOAP envelope from a .txt! Later add your payload to the template!

You can check the next url! Hope it helps!

http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/994/consuming-webservices-in-mule-community-edition-without-datamapper-or-dataweave.html